# cargar archivos csv desde las vistas y desde admin en Django

Tags: html, python, django, csv

estoy haciendo un app en a que necesito implementar la carga de archivos csv (json, xml...) para incorporar los datos al modelo. He creado la siguiente vista en mi app

```
def import_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        archivo_csv = request.FILES.get('archivo_csv')

        if archivo_csv:
            try:
                content = archivo_csv.read()
                encoding = 'utf-8' 
                try:
                    data_set = tablib.Dataset().load(content.decode(encoding), format='csv')
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    data_set = tablib.Dataset().load(content.decode('latin-1'), format='csv')
                product_resource = resources.modelresource_factory(model=ArticuloDisponible)
                resultado = product_resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=True)
                
                if resultado.has_errors():
                    product_resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=False)

                return HttpResponse("Importación exitosa")
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(f"Error al procesar el archivo CSV: {e}")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("No se proporcionó un archivo CSV")

    return render(request, '********.html')
```

tras arrancar el servidor entro sin problema en la vista y todo funciona hasta la carga del archivo  pero me da un error de codificación por lo que no se puede comprobar la funcionalidad de la vista. alguien sabria decirme que esta pasando?

Comment: Necesitas presentar el descripción de tu error.